# Color of coordinates in image using Python

Tags: python, image

Is there any simple way to get the color of a coordinate in python of an image?
I already know the coordinates for instances, just want to know its color in any format.

I have checked around and can't find the answer but apologise if this is a stupid question.

Thanks!

Comment: what image, what module? If you use image with OpenCV then you have numpy array and you can get `image[Y][X]`. Module `pillow` has also method to get pixel color - or you can convert image to numpy array. And `PyGame` should also has own method for this and it should also has method to convert image to numpy array. You should choose module and search in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem that complicated. I think I might have not got your question correctly. But let me still try.

So let's just create a random image first and then fill it with some random colours and then find value of any random coordinate.

```
>>> import cv2 as cv

>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> %matplotlib inline

>>> img = np.zeros((9,9,3), dtype='uint8')

>>> img2 = cv.rectangle(img, (0,0), (2,2), (255, 255, 255), -1)
>>> img2 = cv.rectangle(img, (2,2), (4,4), (255, 0, 255), -1)
>>> img2 = cv.rectangle(img, (4,4), (6,6), (0, 255, 255), -1)
>>> img2 = cv.rectangle(img, (6,6), (8,8), (255, 255, 0), -1)

>>> plt.imshow(cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

[image]

Now let's say we want the color at (2,2). So it's pretty simple and basic actually.

```
>>> print(img2[2,2])
array([255,   0, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

This (255, 0, 255) is your (BGR) value. I am plotting using matplotlib and it uses RGB format, so that's why converting BGR to RGB first. But that's topic of some other day.

So since color images are 3 channel images. For the color at a particular coordinate, all you need to do is put the coordinate value inside the numpy array(the way you'll usually get if you read any random image as well).

Though I am not sure if you meant to ask this only. Does this answers your question?